# android device showing "My application keeps stoping "

Tags: java, android

**mainactivity.java**

```
    package com.example.myapplication;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private WebView mywebview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings=mywebview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myresource.html");
        mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mywebview.canGoBack()) {
            mywebview.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>12/13 23:40:42: Launching 'app' on Physical Device.
```

Install successfully finished in 14 s 668 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.SplashActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 25636 on device 'xiaomi-redmi_7a-2c5b9bbe0406'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
I/FeatureParser: can't find pine.xml in assets/device_features/,it may be in /system/etc/device_features
E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.myapplication
E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
Fail to get file list com.example.myapplication
getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 25636
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.SplashActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example.myapplication:drawable/background with resource ID #0x7f07005f
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3304)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3443)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2040)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:221)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7520)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example.myapplication:drawable/background with resource ID #0x7f07005f
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f07005f
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:898)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.originalLoadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:679)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:586)
at android.content.res.MiuiResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(MiuiResourcesImpl.java:307)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:920)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:859)
at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:696)
at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:454)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:144)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:411)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:86)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.attachToWindow(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:647)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureWindow(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:623)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:350)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:105)
at com.example.myapplication.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:11)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7880)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3279)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3443)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2040)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:221)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7520)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4:  tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflateLayers(LayerDrawable.java:278)
at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:199)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:144)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1402)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1361)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.createFromXmlForDensity(ResourcesImpl.java:1615)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadXmlDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:963)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:882)
... 30 more
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25636 SIG: 9

```
**splashactivity.java**
    package com.example.myapplication;
    
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problems in your splashActivity not the main activity look for drawables that you use for your splash xml file you must import them correctly in your
res->drawable folder of your project weather they are vectors or pngs. Just try to import them in the right place.If it doesnt solve the the problem please put your splash xml file so I can help you.

Update:

Look at your splashactivity it doesnt have any content view
You must create layout for your splash activity .
Go to your project packages expand res folder then right click on layout and create a layout resource then name it  as you prefere for example splash with lowercase then in your splash activity under oncreate method add:

setContentView(R.layout.splash.xml);

Put this line right after super.onCreate(savedinstancestate)

Comment: i have added the splash file

Comment: what I meant,is your splash.xml file and the resources you used for it.

Comment: i had not used splash.xml file 
can you please write it for me

Comment: Any time you want to create an activity just right click on your java package and instead of creating a class just choose activity and then create a blank activity it will autogenerate xml file for you